AWS Amplify Custom Domain - external domain in HostedZone
I am trying to connect my domain to AWS Applify.

I purchased the domain from a third party provider.
I set up a dedicated HostedZone for it with Route53.
I connected the addresses from the NS record to my third party provider.
The connection works because I added 3 more records for the email provider (2 times TXT and one MX for mail. Everything works fine).
when I go to the application in Applify and try to add a domain, I get an error. It just adds a simple address and www, both for the main office. I select the Amplify certificate.


Before adding my Route53 only has 5 records:

NS and SOA - added automatically by AWS on creation
2 x TXT - added to handle mail
MX - added to handle mail.

I do not have another HostedZone. What could be the reason?
